# Are questions about academic club on to topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

The question I'm about to ask is how to gently tell a person in a discuss group that they overtalks and try to take the leader position but fails to make a good, agreed by others argument.

> ## What topics can I ask about here?
>
> The Workplace Stack Exchange is a Q&A site about the workplace and
>   other career-related topics. With your help we're working to build a
>   library to every question about the workplace related to:
>
> - Finding employment (resumes/cv/cover letters, recruiters, hiring-managers, interviews, negotiations, etc.)
> - Maintaining employment (promotions, pay increases, harassment, bullying, poor working conditions, communication problems, etc.)
> - Leadership in the workplace (motivating people, encouraging people, making decisions, holding hard conversations, intervening in unproductive situations, asking for and giving help, etc.)
> - Terminating employment (notice period, breaking the news, handing over work, reference letters, relieving letters, etc.)

If it's not, I think this kind of question may be on topic on Community Building SE.

<sub>This question was first asked in Academia. I was suggested that [Workplace was more suitable](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1822/are-questions-about-academic-club-on-toptic/1823?noredirect=1#comment7681_1823).</sub>

Are questions about academic club on to topic here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is asked in the context of the workplace, such as an office environment or other place of employment, then yes, it would be on-topic. If it's in an academic setting, then that could possibly be on topic depending on whether or not the problem still fits a workplace setting.

The bigger challenge to overcome is to write your question in a way to where you stick to facts. Avoid complicated or extended explanations or too many examples of a person's behavior. Such questions can easily appear to be rants instead of constructive posts seeking a resolution to the problem.  The best way to ensure your post is accepted by the community is to be as organized in your writing and coherent as possible.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm still confused. Is my question on topic or not?

Comment: As I mentioned, it depends on context. Try to focus on your question's details from a workplace perspective rather than an academic one and you should be fine. But without seeing the actual details of your question it is hard to issue guarantees.